# Cannot start ubuntu 17.04 - Can't request region for resource

Tags: xubuntu

I cannot start ubuntu 17.04, I finishing the install Ubuntu with param nomodeset=0, but I cannot start with below issue:

[issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e4hS.jpg)

Comment: Boot again with `nomodeset` and then install Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the installation just fails.
Best guess is to format the partition (maybe even remove and recreate) and try again, since it was a clean install.
Has another version of linux ever run on this pc ?